# How to initialize the dataSource, transactionManager configuration beans later after the server startup?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am aware of initializing the dataSource and transactionManager  beans. But we have a requirement where at the time of server startup, database may not be available so we don't want to initialize these beans at the time of server startup otherwise we used to see the exception in logs.

We are using @Configuration, @EnableJpaRepositories annotation for managing the persistence context.

Can we achieve such kind of configuration in Spring where we want to initialize the  dataSource bean at the time of first API request i.e. lazily?

Comment: Maybe you can give a look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.html)

Answer (score 0):

**If** you are using Spring **boot**, can exclude as below

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Hi Sundararaj, we are not using Spring boot we are doing configurations using AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.